# Unable to echo a file read with fread

Tags: php

I'm trying to read a small html file but when I echo the results I don't see anything. The read/display code is:

```
    $headerName = "header.html";
    $header = fread($header_fp,filesize($headerName));
    $header_filesize = filesize($headerName);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo ("<br />header: file size = $header_filesize data = $header");
    echo "</pre>";
```

The $header_filesize prints as 110, which is correct.

The header.html file I'm reading is:

```
<!doctype html> 
<!-- HTML5  -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Webplaces</title>
</head>
<body>
```

The above is what I was expecting to see with the echoes.

Does anyone see why the echoes don't show the file contents?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are rendering it in a browser. So it renders as HTML. Check the source or `htmlspecialchars()` that shit.

Comment: True that, your rendering non-display tags, if you view the source of the html in the browser you will likely see it.  If your looking for a slightly easier solution to reading the file try `file_get_contents`, but it is not so different to what you are doing already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you escape the html-chars? if you just echo the content it will be handles as normal html and you cannot see it in output.

Try this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($header, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Yes, htmlspecialchars() displays the HTML as I want.  The problem, as everyone has said, is  that the echo goes to the browser and the browser doesn't display tags.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try View Source? HTML gets rendered in a browser.

That said, why are you doing all that? Just use [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) or (if you want PHP to be run) [`include`](http://php.net/include).

Comment: readfile (and include) echo the output to the browser.  That's not at all what I want to do.  I want to read the file, combinine it with something I've ajaxed up to the server, and write the combination to a new file.

Comment: Then try [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

Answer (score 0):

`fread()` doesn' t take a filename, rather then a filesystem pointer!

You have to use `fopen()` before hand:

```
$header_handle = fopen($header_name, "r");
$header = fread($header_handle, filesize($header_name);
// ...
```

Your mistake was to forget `fopen()` the file.

And don' t forget to `fclose($header_handle);`!

Comment: No.  $header_fp in $header = fread($header_fp,filesize($headerName)); is a file pointer.  I didn't show the $header_fp = fopen("$headerName", "r");

Comment: Then post your complete code in the future please.